# rtsp stream with django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I'm trying to put a url based on my views.py but it returns the error:

**Reverse for 'transmition' not found. 'transmition' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**

[image]

**project urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from plataforma.views import *
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
                  path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
                  path('contas/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
                  path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='index'),
                  path('plataforma/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='plataforma.html'), name='plataforma'),
                  path('plataforma/stream', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='stream.html'), name='stream'),
              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**app urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('plataforma', PlataformaView.as_view(), name='plataforma'),
    path('stream/', StreamView.as_view(), name='stream'),
    path('transmition/', transmition, name='transmition'),
]
```

**app views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.views.decorators import gzip
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

import cv2
import threading


@gzip.gzip_page
def transmition(request):
    try:
        cam = VideoCamera()
        return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(cam), mimetype="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")
    except:
        pass
    # return render(request, 'stream.html')


class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(
            "rtsp://jorge:jorge33621005@189.124.26.190:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1")
        (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.video.read()
        threading.Thread(target=self.update, args=()).start()

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        image = self.frame
        _, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
        return jpeg.tobytes()

    def update(self):
        while True:
            (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.video.read()


def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')


class PlataformaView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'plataforma.html'


class StreamView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'stream.html'
```

**stream.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <img src="{% url 'transmition' %}">
</body>
</html>
```

As I'm a beginner, I couldn't transmit the rtsp stream in the HTML page. I need to stream and style the 'transmition' function.

Comment: What is your `app_name` in `settings.py`? Try it as `<img src="{% url 'your_app_name:transmition' %}">` see if it works, or else you need to define the URL pattern also in project's urls.py.

Comment: My app_name is "plataforma".

Comment: At first try below answer.

Comment: I tried *<img src="{% url 'plataforma:transmition' %}">*,  them i got  *"plataforma' is not a registered namespace"*

Comment: Did you define `app_name='plataforma'` in app's urls.py?

Comment: Yes. i did it. But i didn't get any answer

Comment: Try edited answer, see it correctly from top to bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `app_name` in app's urls.py, like so:

```py
from django.urls import path

from .views import *

app_name='plataforma'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PlataformaView.as_view(), name='plataforma_view'),
    path('stream/', StreamView.as_view(), name='stream'),
    path('transmition/', transmition, name='transmition'),
]
```

Then use it while calling in URL tag as:

```
<img src="{% url 'plataforma:transmition' %}">
```

You can give any `app_name` according to your need.

### Edit

You should also remove unnecessary routes in project's urls.py, so it should like this:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from plataforma.views import *
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('contas/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='index'),
    path('plataforma/', include('plataforma.urls'), namespace='plataforma')

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: That's works! Now te template's load, but the stream did not load

Comment: @DanAzevedo If the template is loading but the stream is not, there may be an issue with the `transmition` function in your `views.py` file. You should check to make sure that the video stream is being captured and sent to the browser correctly.

Comment: Yeah, Thank you for your attention. I'll review the "transmition" code